# Strings.xml and append

Tags: java, android, append, settext

I am playing a bit around with Android after doing a number of tutorials.

I have a textview in which I want to print various lines of text that I have written in the strings.xml file:

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome! What is your name?</string>
<string name="welcome2">Welcome!</string>
```

In my main I have:

```
gamehistory = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
gamehistory.setText(R.string.welcome);
```

This works fine and it displays the text. I want to use the textbox as a "log" so that a bit later in my code it prints welcome2 in the next line.

```
gamehistory.append("\n" + R.string.welcome2);
```

Unfortunately, when I use append, it turns the string into a number.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: R.string.welcome2 is integer resource string id. You should get String itself. getReources().getString(R.string.welcome2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append i think will not be there but yes you can concatenate like this

```
String outStr = getString(R.string.first) + 
  " " + getString(R.string.second);
```

For Refrence [Link to refrence](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String welcomestr = Context.getResources().getString(R.string.welcome2)
    gamehistory = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    gamehistory.setText(welcomestr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Context.getResources().getString(id)` for that.

```
getReources().getString(R.string.welcome2); // Since you're calling this in your activity itself.
```

because `R.string.welcome2` is an auto generated integer value for your string resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding carriage return.

```
gamehistory.append("\r\n" + R.string.welcome2);
```

Or add these lines to TextView part of xml:

```
android:maxLines="2"
android:minLines="1"
```